# Loading multiple sets of annotations onto map kit map

Tags: ios, json, mapkit, mkannotation

im trying to show on a map two json files simulteniously. But there is the problem it gives me weird errors which I can't figure it out. So originaly there was

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSMutableArray * annotations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    self.mapView.visibleMapRect = MKMapRectMake(135888858.533591, 92250098.902419, 190858.927912, 145995.678292);
    NSLog(@"Loading data…");
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
        NSData * JSONData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:self.seedFileName ofType:@"json"]];


        for (NSDictionary * annotationDictionary in [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:JSONData options:kNilOptions error:NULL])
        {
            ADClusterableAnnotation * annotation = [[ADClusterableAnnotation alloc] initWithDictionary:annotationDictionary];
            [annotations addObject:annotation];
            [annotation release];
        }

     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"Building KD-Tree…");
            [self.mapView setAnnotations:annotations];
        });
    });

    [annotations release];
}
```

so i saw that i have two ViewControllers which holds the the seedfile
this one is

```
#import "CDStreetlightsMapViewController.h"

@implementation CDStreetlightsMapViewController

- (NSString *)pictoName {
    return @"CDStreetlight.png";
}

- (NSString *)clusterPictoName {
    return @"CDStreetlightCluster.png";
}

- (NSString *)seedFileName {
    return @"CDStreetlights";
}
- (NSString *)seedFileName1 {
    return @"CDToilets";
}
@end
```

the other one is

```
#import "CDToiletsMapViewController.h"

@implementation CDToiletsMapViewController

- (NSString *)seedFileName {
    return @"CDToilets";
}

- (NSString *)pictoName {
    return @"CDToilet.png";
}

- (NSString *)clusterPictoName {
    return @"CDToiletCluster.png";
}

@end
```

The json files are named CDToilets and CDStreetlights... but i have a tab bar which holds Toilets and streetlights. But lets say i would like to display on the toilets viewController the streetlights and the toilets? thats my problem right know.. I tried this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSMutableArray * annotations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    self.mapView.visibleMapRect = MKMapRectMake(135888858.533591, 92250098.902419, 190858.927912, 145995.678292);
    NSLog(@"Loading data…");

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
        NSData * JSONData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:self.seedFileName ofType:@"json"]];


        for (NSDictionary * annotationDictionary in [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:JSONData options:kNilOptions error:NULL])
        {
            ADClusterableAnnotation * annotation = [[ADClusterableAnnotation alloc] initWithDictionary:annotationDictionary];
            [annotations addObject:annotation];
            [annotation release];
        }

        NSData * JSONData1 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:self.seedFileName1 ofType:@"json"]];


        for (NSDictionary * annotationDictionary in [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:JSONData1 options:kNilOptions error:NULL])
        {
            ADClusterableAnnotation * annotation = [[ADClusterableAnnotation alloc] initWithDictionary:annotationDictionary];
            [annotations addObject:annotation];
            [annotation release];
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"Building KD-Tree…");
            [self.mapView setAnnotations:annotations];
        });
    });

    [annotations release];   
}
```

i renamed in the `CDStreetlightsMapViewController` the `seedfile` as `seedfile1` so i can use it two times in `viewDidLoad` it didn't show errors but it didn't run well on simulator and I get an exception:

```
ClusterDemo[11014:c07]Loading data…
ClusterDemo[11014:1303]***Assertion failure in -[CDToiletsMapViewController seedFileName1], ADClusterMapView-master-7/ClusterDemo/Classes/CDMapViewController.‌​m:86 2013-11-25 23:59:37.524
ClusterDemo[11014:1303]***Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'This abstract method must be overridden!' *** First throw call stack: (0x18b2012 0x1277e7e 0x18b1e78 0xd0df35 0x3fad 0x36cb 0x2deb53f 0x2dfd014 0x2dee2e8 0x2dee450 0x99843e72 0x9982bdaa) libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception (lldb)
```

you can download the full app here... https://github.com/applidium/ADClusterMapView

Comment: And what didn't work when you loaded both sets of annotations into the single array? What is the problem?

Comment: the app showed for 1 second and crashed.

Comment: Give details of the exception. Don't expect people to guess.

Comment: ClusterDemo[11014:c07]Loading data…
ClusterDemo[11014:1303]***Assertion failure in -[CDToiletsMapViewController seedFileName1], /Users/andrew/ADClusterMapView-master-7/ClusterDemo/Classes/CDMapViewController.m:86
2013-11-25 23:59:37.524 ClusterDemo[11014:1303]***Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'This abstract method must be overridden!'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x18b2012 0x1277e7e 0x18b1e78 0xd0df35 0x3fad 0x36cb 0x2deb53f 0x2dfd014 0x2dee2e8 0x2dee450 0x99843e72 0x9982bdaa)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the exception it's quite clear that you're using an abstract method that contains an assertion to ensure that you know you've made a mistake. You need to implement the `seedFileName1` method in `CDToiletsMapViewController` (just like you did in `CDStreetlightsMapViewController`).

From the code I guess you need to add:

```
- (NSString *)seedFileName1 {
    return @"CDStreetlights";
}
```

Comment: Im new to xcode so it's hard understand term like "concrete implementation". Can you be please be more specific, what should i do to run the void correctly?

Comment: That code is a guess, you need to add that method and I guess that return value will work...

Comment: wow! it doesnt crash know, but i wanted that in the toiletsViewController the toilets and streetlights cluster would appear

Comment: I guess you get all the annotations but the image pins displayed are wrong?

Comment: There is only image pins for toilet annotations...but the streetlight annotations and image pins are not showing...

Comment: Adds one logging to check what is running and what the annotations created are.

Comment: I checked the app cerefuly and i pressed on a Tabbar button the Toilets icon... opens a Map and loads only toilets i zoomed in and checked maby there is some streetlights annotation in there... but no... basically i added a loop and a new variable which does nothing :/

Comment: sorry both the loop and a variable does nothing... if it does then it's not displayed on Map

Comment: Is the code getting run? You need to log / debug to find out.

Comment: Is there some way that i can write this line  NSData * JSONData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:self.seedFileName ofType:@"json"]];

but with two variables (seedfile variables) like this
 NSData * JSONData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:self.seedFileName, self.seedFileName1 ofType:@"json"]];

i know its wrong but you get the idea

Comment: No, but the code you have looks ok, that's why you need to debug to check what gets called and what it does.

Comment: It works! everything is fine it shows both json files... i have to change the cluster picture know! Thank you!